# How to change program's name in Makefile.am

Tags: syntax, makefile, autotools

Currently the code in makefile.am is like this:

```
performancetestsdir = $(prefix)/tests/@PACKAGE@/performance-test
performancetests_PROGRAMS = eventwindowperformancetest
```

I would like to make the program 'eventwindowperformancetest' in the name of 'oldeventwindowperformancetest' after building

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

several possibilities:

change the name in the Makefile.am to the one you want (what's the point in building program as XY when you really want to have it as XX?)

use the "--program-transform-name" flag to configure to transform the name of your output program

add a post-build hook that renames your file for you. something like:

```
all-local: oldeventwindowperformancetest
oldeventwindowperformancetest: eventwindowperformancetest
        cp "$^" "$@"
```